# How to redirect "localhost:port" or my "ip:port" to a node process running on a different port than nginx?

Tags: node.js, http, nginx, localhost

We have some computers connected through LAN. I have a node process running locally on the port 5000.
I wanna direct the requests "***andy.dev***" to my node process .
It should be the same when accessed from all computers.
I'm on windows7. I have nginx installed.
I have only a **conf** folder, **NO** *sites available* or anyother like the old configuration for nginx. So I'll be happy if you explain me how to configure nginx(newer version) to do this or directly through nodejs.
I have been reading about virtual host in google but really dont understand how to set it up.
**NOTE**: I dont have admin rights.
Any help will be greatly appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: Do requests access the node server directly on the port 5000 ? or is there a URL that maps to it ?

Comment: Yes it is. It directly listens on 5000.

Comment: Well then nginx doesn't have control here, because you access node directly without going through nginx. You need node to do the redirect